# Different results running the same job on Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, talend

I created a Talend job which imports data from a SQL database into a TMS database.
During this job, a varchar field is translated into an integer field. This is done in two steps: First I check if the varchar field is an Integer and if it's true, I convert it, else it becomes 0 (zero).
To do this, a piece of code is used:

```
package routines;
public class MyRoutines {
 public static Boolean isNumeric(String str) {
if(str.equals("")){  return false; }
 for(int i=str.length();--i>=0;){ 
 int chr=str.charAt(i); 
if((chr<48&&chr!=46&&chr!=45&&chr!=44)|| chr>57)   return false;  } return true;   }}
```

This is in my tMap:

```
MyRoutines.isNumeric((Relational.ISNULL(row1.WagenparkNummer)?"a":row1.WagenparkNummer))?Integer.parseInt(row1.WagenparkNummer):0
```

I created the job with Talend 5.1.2.r90681 and tested it on Windows 7.0. A random record says '001554' in SQL. After conversion the field is saved as 1554 in the TMS database.
I exported the job and extracted the zip file on a Linux system. (Nothing special, I have done this before for around 40 jobs).
And now the strange thing: After running the job on Linux, the same record is converted to 15 instead of 1554.
Why???

It only effects records with leading zero's. Records without leading zero's are converted in the correct way.
(Example given: '002534' is converted wrongly to 25. '2534' is converted to 2534.)

EDIT 8-5-2015: (also read the comments ;-) )
The field in the output table is a Numeric field. (Not signed with +/-, so negative numbers are impossible). Via ODBC the numbers are inserted in the correct way. Via JDBC the numbers are inserted in the wrong way. If I change the numeric field into a signed numeric field, the numbers are inserted in the table in the correct way via both JDBC and ODBC.

Comment: I tip on wrong column definition; maybe different db version. Maybe a bug in your linux version of OpenJDK? Never heard. Unprobable but you might try `parseInt(..., 10)` explicitly using base 10.

Comment: $ java --showversion
java version "1.4.2"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)

Comment: (Oh boy) Go for `1.7`, maybe from oracle if there is no newer version. I did not knew 1.4 has autoboxing: `Boolean` should actually better be `boolean`, not the object wrapper.

Comment: What do you mean with 'autoboxing' ?

Comment: `boolean, int, double` are the primitive types; `Boolean, Integer, Double` are Object classes, with a corresponding primitive value, to use the values as Object. Hence a Boolean can be null, or two Object values: Boolean.FALSE and Boolean.TRUE. The newer java versions can convert between the two abstractions, that is called autoboxing, automatic placing a `boolean`(false, true) into a box (`Boolean`).

Comment: I created a test job, only having a tJava component with this code:

    `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("0012345"));`

It returns `12345` on the linux machine...
Now I really don't have a clue where it goes wrong.

Comment: It could be an encoding issue, though for a simple string with all numbers this does seem unlikely.  But its worth trying a String.codePointCount() to see if for some reason the characters are spanning multiple CharAt values.

Comment: Forget the leading zero's it's a different story:
I found a difference in the JDBC and ODBC connection. Don't know where to look further and how to solve. But via the ODBC connection, everything goes right, via the JDBC connection it goes wrong.

Comment: The field in the output table is a Numeric field. (Not signed with +/-, so negative numbers are impossible).
Via ODBC the numbers are inserted in the correct way. Via JDBC the numbers are inserted in the wrong way.

If I change the numeric field into a signed numeric field, the numbers are inserted in the table in the correct way via both JDBC and ODBC.